# My Office Suite always looks like Window Classic Style

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-office, themes

I'm not sure if this is the correct forum to ask such a question, but i'm hoping someone can help me in any case.

I have Office 2007 with the exception of Outlook 2007 installed on my pc. In addition to Office 2007, i have Outlook 2003 installed. Anyways my Office theme for all Office products and all versions looks like the "Ugly Classic Windows 2000 Theme". How do i get my office to appear correctly. My OS theme is set to Windows XP. My themes service is started. I don't have any video driver conflicts. I've searched and searched on the net and have found nothing that helps. Re-imaging PC is not an option.

If anyone can provide me with any type of help at all, i would greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Besides Outlook 2003, isn't secretly the entire 2003 Office suite installed? So that it might be you're starting Word 2003 etc. instead of their respective 2007 versions?

Answer (score 0):

Look in Device Manager for SMS Mirror driver under Display Adapters and delete or disable it and then reboot.